# I want to implement OTP automation using Capybara. Any suggestion is highly appreciable

Tags: capybara

I am trying to implement OTP automation using Capybara. The scenario is

1. User is clicking on the Login Page
2. User is shown a modal where he/she needs to enter the phone number
3. OTP would be generated and sent back to the previously entered mobile number.
4. User uses the OTP to login to the application.

**Challenge :** Accessing the generated OTP from a different platform [SMS from Mobile/some other platform] to feed it in the OTP text box.

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Filling in the OTP input is no different than filling in any other text input - the real question is how you have access to the OTP necessary and that's really going to depend on what you're using to do the OTP generation, does that package have a test mode, etc, etc.  If you add that info to your question you may get useful help

Comment: @ThomasWalpole : Thanks for your response. Yes, you are correct. Accessing the generated OTP is the challenge. I am trying to figure out how to achieve the same. Do you have any suggestion ? I am updating the question above though.